# Difficulty accessing multi-dimensional array from JSON data

Tags: python, json

Here is the JSON data in question:

```
{
  "result_index": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.994,
          "transcript": "thunderstorms could produce large hail isolated tornadoes and heavy rain "
        }
      ],
      "final": true
    }
  ]
```

}

Here is how I am attemption to access it.

```
parsed = json.loads(data)
print(parsed['results']['alternatives']['transcript'])
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

It seems as though results is just an array with a single entry that is a string, and I am a bit confused how to access the individual elements within it.

Comment: `results` and `alternatives` are arrays so maybe `parsed['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']`

Comment: That was it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your `results` and `alternatives` are not objects; but arrays of objects.

```
print(parsed['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

Comment: Yup, that did it, thanks for the explanation as well.